# bash source command and the filename of the script

Tags: macos, bash

I have a bash script that will need to be executed using the bash built-in `source`. But it needs to read its own filename and update `PATH` based on it. Unfortunately, `$0` does not contain the name of the script. So the following does *not work*.

```
ABSDIR=$(pwd)/$(dirname "$0")
export PATH="$ABSDIR/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

Is there a way to get the name of the script file in this context?

```
source ~/CLTools/Clang-5.0/activate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:

```
echo ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "take a look"? Try to expand the answer to make it something more than a comment.